# Proving a relationship involving the chemical potential

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

I need to prove the relation $$\left(\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial N}\right)_{T,V}> \left(\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial N}\right)_{T,P}.$$

One may start with the total differential of the internal energy, $U (S,V,N)$ $$dU = TdS-PdV + \mu dN.$$

I do not know how to go from here. Can you give me suggestion or propose a solution ? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to derive the internal energy with respect to $N$ twice?

Comment: that subscript T,V means T and V are constant?

Comment: While it's possible to understand you question as is, please be aware that many  notations aren't universal. It'd help if you indicated 1) what theory / framework you're working in, 2) what law you're talking about, 3) what your notations mean. Thanks.

Comment: It is about thermodynamics, $\mu$ is the chemical potential, $N$ the count of atoms/molecules in the system.

Comment: Note that $\mu=\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial N}\right)_{T,P}$, where $dG=-S\,dT+V\,dP+\mu\,dN$. Try differentiating that with respect to $N$ under conditions of constant $T,V$ and $T,P$.

Comment: Thanks. I do not see how this will lead to the required inequality.